# CGIProxy running on macOS fails to connect to sites using SSL

Tags: macos, proxy, ssl, webserver, perl

I'm trying to run a web proxy [CGIProxy](https://jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/) on one of my home servers that's running macOS 10.11.6. I've set up the web server using Apple's Server utility.

By and large it works, but there's a few websites that when I try to connect to them via HTTPS it fails with the following error:

> Net::SSLeay::read error: SSL_read 8284: 1 - error:14077410:lib(20):func(119):reason(1040)

Unfortunately I'm not particularly experienced with web servers or Perl so I have little idea what this means or how to fix it.

As an experiment, I set up an Ubuntu 14.04 server on a virtual machine, setup apache2, and installed CGIProxy on that, and it works just fine -- no SSL errors when connecting to the problematic sites.

So it looks like this has something to do with macOS being a bit of a different beast than Linux, which is not surprising. I've encountered several SSL-related problems with macOS systems before under different circumstances.

Any idea how to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So digging into this error more, I discovered it indicates a handshake error, likely due to macOS not having a properly up-to-date version of OpenSSL. Executing `openssl version` prints `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh` which doesn't support TLS 1.1 or 1.2, which is likely why it was failing.

The solution was to use homebrew to install a separate version of perl that links against homebrew's copy of OpenSSL. The current version of perl in homebrew as of me writing this is 5.24.1, which is newer than the version provided with macOS abd Ubuntu 14.04. When I installed it and tried running using it to execute CGIProxy, it crashed. So I instead tried perl 5.18, which did the trick.

In summary, the following fixes it:

```
brew install perl@5.18
brew link --force perl@5.18
```

Edit nph-proxy.cgi and change the first shebang line from:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

To:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
```

Cleared out ~/.cpan and ~/perl5 if you already ran `./nph-proxy init`, run `./nph-proxy.cgi init` again, and after it finished, I had no trouble using CGIProxy to access the websites that were problematic before.